# Как запустить скрипт по сети?

Tags: сеть, bat, скрипт

```
rasdial VPN_1 /disconnect & timeout 5 & taskkill /f /im cloud.exe & timeout 5 & start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cloud\Cloud\bin\launcher.exe"
```

Локально скрипт работает.
Можно-ли как-то запустить проверку с одного компа внутри локальной сети на ещё 5 компах, ip которых статичны 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12 и т.д.?

Comment: А ты что в будущем-то получить хочешь? Хочешь запускать с одной тачки установку или настройку проги и чтобы это всё разливалось на компы внутри сети?